# JAVA read write com port

Tags: java, arduino, serial-port, port

I have an Arduino which sends me the string **ping**, and as you can see in my code, when I read **ping**, I write **pong**

It's like a watchdog. But the line: output.write("pong".getBytes()); is not working well. I do can read, but cannot write.

Anyone can help me please?

```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier; 
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent; 
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener; 
import java.util.Enumeration;


public class SerialTest implements SerialPortEventListener {
    SerialPort serialPort;
        /** The port we're normally going to use. */
    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
            "/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
                        "/dev/ttyACM0", // Raspberry Pi
            "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
            "COM3", // Windows
    };
    /**
    * A BufferedReader which will be fed by a InputStreamReader 
    * converting the bytes into characters 
    * making the displayed results codepage independent
    */
    private BufferedReader input;
    /** The output stream to the port */
    private OutputStream output;
    /** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
    /** Default bits per second for COM port. */
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 115200;

    public void initialize() {
                // the next line is for Raspberry Pi and 
                // gets us into the while loop and was suggested here was suggested http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=32186
              //  System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev/ttyACM0");

        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                    portId = currPortId;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (portId == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                    TIME_OUT);

            // set port parameters
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            // open the streams
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            // add event listeners
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This should be called when you stop using the port.
     * This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
     */
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }
    }






    /**
     * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
     */
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine=input.readLine();
                System.out.println(inputLine);
                if(inputLine.equals("ping")){
                    System.out.println("pong");

                    output.write("pong".getBytes());

                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("no");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SerialTest main = new SerialTest();
        main.initialize();
        Thread t=new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000 seconds,
                //waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
                try {Thread.sleep(1000000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        };
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Started");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `output.flush()` after the call to `write`? The stream could be buffered. Alternatively you might need a newline character in your string according to whatever protocol, so "pong\n" instead

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that you are using `readLine` to read the `"ping"` I am going to guess and say that you also have to write a newline character at the end of your `"pong"`. You may also need to flush the output stream if it is a buffered stream.

So,

```
output.write("pong\n".getBytes());
output.flush(); // this line might be unnecessary, but try it and see
```

Answer (score 0):

> But the line: output.write("pong".getBytes()); is not working well.

More precisely, please.

What if you turn your test around:
Whenever your java sends something to Arduino, arduino returns it and java shows what is received in the SerialEvent callback